# Why can't i declare a variable which does not mutated/change in mojo

Tags: python, mojolang

why can't i import python code in mojo

```
from python import Python
let np = Python.import_module("numpy")
```

this gives me error

```
/home/kali/hello.mojo:2:30: error: cannot call function that may raise in a context that cannot raise
let np = Python.import_module("numpy")
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/home/kali/hello.mojo:2:30: note: try surrounding the call in a 'try' block
let np = Python.import_module("numpy")
                             ^
/home/kali/.modular/pkg/packages.modular.com_mojo/bin/mojo: error: failed to parse the provided Mojo
```

even in the example code of mojo in hello_interop_mojo code:

```
from python.python import (
    Python,
    _destroy_python,
    _init_python,
)


def main():
    print("Hello Mojo !")
    for x in range(9, 0, -3):
        print(x)
    try:
        Python.add_to_path(".")
        Python.add_to_path("./examples")
        let test_module = Python.import_module("simple_interop")
        test_module.test_interop_func()
    except e:
        print(e.value)
        print("could not find module simple_interop")
```

i get this error :

```
Hello Mojo !
9
6
3
An error occurred in Python.
could not find module simple_interop
```

i am running mojo on wsl ubuntu image

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mojo docs, you need to use Python.add_to_path() to specify a path to the module that you want to import. So, the modified code would be:

```
from python import Python

Python.add_to_path("path/to/module")
let np = Python.import_module("numpy")
```

For more info: [Mojo Docs](https://docs.modular.com/mojo/stdlib/python/python.html)

Comment: Are you ok with this code on your mojo version ? On mine, your second and third rows generate the same error message saying mojo can't deal with exceptions. Or maybe there is something I missed ?

Comment: @LaurentB. It does work for me in a Mojo notebook in JupyterLab

Answer (score 1):

**Actually, Mojo can't deal with direct Python importation**

Actually there is no way to import python modules on the fly in a Mojo REPL session (terminal) unless you open the Python notebook as follows :

```
%%python #Open the Python notebook
import numpy as np

print(np.sqrt(10))
```

```
3.1622776601683795
```

[image]

**Your Python importation**

Mojo does not support exceptions actually and that's why you have this error :
`error: cannot call function that may raise in a context that cannot raise`.

Plus, `let` and `var` are not used at a global level but inside a `def`or restrictive `fn`function.

I suggest you use a function instead and, to prevent errors you should add `raises`after that function in your code.

**Proposed script:**

```
from python import Python as py

fn main() raises:
    let np = py.import_module("numpy")
    print(np.sqrt(10))
```

In Visual Studio it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

On your first issue

```
from python import Python
let np = Python.import_module("numpy")
```

`let np = Python.import_module("numpy")` has to be called in a function that either has raises or the assignment is in a `try ... catch` block. Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77082774/16376310) answer.

On the second issue, you need to have [simple_interop.py](https://github.com/modularml/mojo/blob/a785148a149e3537b7e3ed000267641c12d22976/examples/simple_interop.py) in the same folder where is the code you are executing.